# Is a GetBucketAcl API call normal/expected when using the .NET AWS SDK?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the .NET AWS SDK and I was able to monitor a rogue ACL call - `GetBucketAcl`.

Is this normal/expected?

Is it possible to turn off this call?

Currently, I'm having a `https://<url>/?acl` request to the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this normal/expected?

Yes - it's an internal call made by the .NET SDK to [return the access control list (ACL) of a bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetBucketAcl.html) for checking permissions.

You're probably seeing it while trying to do a [`ListBuckets`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html) operation.

> Is it possible to turn off this call?

No, unless you decide to stop using the SDK and directly call the API endpoints you need (which I wouldn't recommend).